# NUMBA: Ahead-of-Time issues

Tags: python, numba, precompile, numba-pro

I'm trying to use [numba](http://numba.pydata.org/) to speed up a slow calculation.  It works great with the `@njit` decorator but I really need it to work as a precompiled [ahead-of-time](http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/user/pycc.html)(AOT) module.  Sadly I haven't been able to get it to work.  Here is the code I use to compile the AOT-module:

```py
from numba.pycc import CC
import numpy as np

cc = CC('window_cloud_scores')
cc.verbose = True
cc.output_dir='/cache'
cc.output_file='window_cloud_scores.so'


@cc.export('run', 'f8[:,:](u1[:,:], i4)')
def run(clouds,window):
    r=int(window/2)
    assert clouds.ndim==2
    assert clouds.shape[0]==clouds.shape[1]
    rows,cols=clouds.shape
    score_map=np.full(clouds.shape,-1)
    scores=[]
    for j in range(r,rows-r):
        score_cols=[]
        for i in range(r,cols-r):
            clouds_window=clouds[j-r:j+r+1,i-r:i+r+1]
            score_cols.append(clouds_window.mean())
        scores.append(score_cols)
    return np.array(scores)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    cc.compile()
```

When I compile the module it creates the `window_cloud_scores.so` file but gives the following warning:

> /Users/.../lib/python3.6/site-packages/numba/pycc/../runtime/_nrt_python.c:234:55: warning: incompatible pointer types passing 'PyTypeObject *' (aka 'struct _typeobject *') to
>         parameter of type 'PyObject *' (aka 'struct _object *') [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
>       mi = (MemInfoObject*)PyObject_CallFunctionObjArgs(&MemInfoType, addr, NULL);
>                                                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~
>   /Users/.../python3.6m/abstract.h:425:68: note: passing argument to parameter 'callable' here
>        PyAPI_FUNC(PyObject *) PyObject_CallFunctionObjArgs(PyObject *callable,

And then when I try to run

```py
import window_cloud_scores as wcs
wcs.run(...)
```

I get a `segmentation fault: 11` in the python console and it a jupyter notebook the kernel dies.

And again,

```py
@njit
def run(clouds,window):
    r=int(window/2)
    assert clouds.ndim==2
    assert clouds.shape[0]==clouds.shape[1]
    rows,cols=clouds.shape
    score_map=np.full(clouds.shape,-1)
    scores=[]
    for j in range(r,rows-r):
        score_cols=[]
        for i in range(r,cols-r):
            clouds_window=clouds[j-r:j+r+1,i-r:i+r+1]
            score_cols.append(clouds_window.mean())
        scores.append(score_cols)
    return np.array(scores)
```

Works great.  Thoughts?

Comment: Works for me. What's your numba version?

Comment: Btw: The way you're using numba isn't really utilizing the power of numba. I wouldn't expect "really significant" speed-ups with this function except when you have small really small windows.

Comment: @MSeifert - Thanks for jumping on this.  I'm using `numba==0.43.1`, its in a conda environment (`Python 3.6.7`)  if that makes a difference.

Comment: @MSeifert - as for speed ups.  My window size in 17.  I would figure most of the speed up though was from the nested for loops... ie `clouds_window.mean()` is pretty fast for almost any size window, the issue is that it has to be computed for every pixel.  All that said - i'm new to numba and not sure where its strengths are. For my test case: its about 2 seconds without numba, 700ms for the first numba run and 100ms for the subsequent runs

Comment: Hm have you tried [scipy convolve](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.0/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.filters.convolve.html#scipy.ndimage.filters.convolve)? It's not exactly the same but very similar.

Comment: I hadn't seen scipy-convolve before.  Not quite what I need but its good to know its there. Thanks!